# use regex to parse string using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I am developing a sample code for my customer and haven't done programming in Python before. How do I use regex to extract text below?

```
RSH|^~\&|MIC|SCC|MS4OD|A|201804060738||ORU^R01|0137245|P|2.2
KID|||10552884||Fer^Huh^GRV||20223164433|M||W|193 Biop Mill
```

I want to extract 0137245 from the first row and 10552884 from the second row.

```
RSH|^~\&|MIC|SCC|MS4OD|A|201804060738||ORU^R01|0137246|P|2.3
KID|||10552885||Fer^Huh^GRV||2023164434|M||W|193 jason Mill
```

I want to extract 0137246 from the first row and 10552885 from the second row.

Example 3

```
RSH|^~\&|MIC|SCC|MS4OD|A|201804060738||ORU^R01|01372451.1|P|2.2
KID|1||10552884||Fer^Huh^GRV||20223164433|M||W|193 Biop Mill
```

I want to extract 01372451.1 from the first row and 10552884 from the second row.

Example 4

```
RSH|^~\&|MIC|SCC|MS4OD|A|201804060738||ORU^R01|01372451.1|P|2.2
KID|1|2|10552884||Fer^Huh^GRV||20223164433|M||W|193 Biop Mill
```

I want to extract 01372451.1 from the first row and 10552884 from the second row.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the examples you've given, you could use

```
regex1=re.compile('\|\|ORU\^R01\|(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\|')
regex2=re.compile('^KID\|\d?\|\d?\|(\d+)\|')

match1=regex1.search(firstRow)
if match1 is not None:
    print(match1.groups()[0])

match2=regex2.search(secondRow)
if match2 is not None:
    print(match2.groups()[0])
```

Comment: That helped. I modified original question to include another example. The solution provided worked for example 1 and 2, but did not work for 3.

Comment: For the third example, what would you like to extract?

Comment: for example 3, I want to extract 01372451.1 from the first row and 10552884 from the second row.

Comment: Please check one more example provided in original question...thanks for your help

Comment: There you go.  Updated

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Changes to regex 1 works for all examples. Regex 2 still does not work for example 3 & 4

Comment: Try it now.  I didn't see those digits before.

Answer (score 1):

this is the solution to get the numbers from both the rows or any number of rows

```
str = 'RSH|^~\&|MIC|SCC|MS4OD|A|201804060738||ORU^R01|0137246|P|2.3KID|||10552885||Fer^Huh^GRV||2023164434|M||W|193 jason Mill '
res = re.findall(r'\b\d{7,8}\b',str)
print(res)
```